# How to delete or hide reflections, bounces and refractions from a geometry on render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

I'm making a Prism. It's not based totally on reality, so it can count as a basic representation of it.

As you can see on the image, there are reflections made by the objects, but how can I erase exactly those reflections? I already unchecked the box on the objects that are from 'Transmission' and 'Shadow'...but still I see them on there.

Is there any solution to this?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

**If i add more Roughness to the Glass BSDF, the reflections dissapear, but the transparency isnt the same.**

Comment: reflections are glossy rays

Comment: How can i hide them? or is it impossible?

Comment: uncheck glossy from ray visibility, so this object wont apaer in reflection

Comment: That doesnt work, already tried :(
If i add more Roughness to the Glass BSDF, the reflections dissapear, but the transparency isnt the same.

Comment: Hmm, wait, there was an additional object hidden, i deleted it and it worked, how silly of me..
But yet, the answer you gave me helped, so if you want please post it as an answer because it worked :) Thanks!

Comment: I know this solved already, but in addition to ray visibility, you could have also used seperate render layers and composited the two back together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent an object from appearing as a reflection on other objects, uncheck  **Glossy**  under **Ray Visibility** in the **Object** tab:

[image]