# Disable reflection on a custom material

Tags: rendering, materials

I was making a lightsaber material, and after several days, i have found one, that is "almost perfect". Except it reflects light. Is it possible to add some filter on it, that would disable any reflections, while keeping all other properties, including it emmitting light.

Edit:
[image]
Here is an example file with a few "lightsabers" in a simple scene. The problem is, that for example the "red" one is getting so much refractions, that it ruins it's color.

Comment: Please provide more details. For example, an image of what you currently have and what you're trying to achieve. A picture of your node setup would also help. It's also a good idea to provide us your .Blend file by using [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so we can assist you better. Thanks and welcome to SE :)

Comment: Possible related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24697/how-to-delete-or-hide-reflections-bounces-and-refractions-from-a-geometry-on-re

Comment: After more research ,I have found my anwser here.
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44605/prevent-shadow-on-object-material-a-allow-for-object-material-b/44607#44607